# C++ Enum and function with a variable number of parameters. Unknown error

Tags: c++, function, enums

**Here is my task:** We can transfer these datas **(char, int, and float)** to the function. Before each group we must specify the number of elements in the group, then their type (using enum) and the data itself. Such groups can be any amount. Therefore, at the beginning of the entire list we must indicate the total number of groups to be processed. The task is to **convert data** --- from **char** to **int** and from **float** to **double**

Here is my code. but there is one error. I've never seen it before:
[image]

Can You help me with that. Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdarg.h"
using namespace std;

enum data { Char, Іnt, Float};

int main()
{
    float f1, f2, f3, f4;
    int i1, i2, i3, i4;

    void dіspl(int, int, enum data, ...); 

    do
    {                        
        dіspl(1, 3, Char, 'a', 'b', 'c');    
        cin >> i1 >> i2 >> i3 >> i4;               
        dіspl(2, 4, Іnt, i1, i2, i3, i4, 3, Char, 'a', 'b', 'c');

        cin >> f1 >> f2 >> f3 >> f4 ;
        dіspl(3, 3, Char, 'x', 'z', 't', 3, Іnt, i1, i2, i3, 4, Float, f1, f2, f3, f4);

        cout<<"exіt=0?";
        cin>>i1; 
    } while (i1);

    return 0;
}

// k - count of groups, i - count of elements in first grour, Турe - their type.

void displ(int k, int i, enum data Type, ...){   
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, Type);

    while(k--) {
        switch(Type)
        {
            case Char: while(i--)
                cout << va_arg(arg, char) << "     ";  break;
            case Іnt: while (i--)
                cout << va_arg(arg, int) << "     ";  break;    
            case Float: while(i--)       
                cout << va_arg(arg, double) << "    "; break; 
            default:
                cout << "Type=ERROR";
                return;         
        }
        cout << endl;  i =  va_arg(arg, int);
        Type = va_arg(arg, enum data); 

    }

    va_end(arg);
}
```

Comment: `void displ(int k, int i, enum data Type, ...){` You can omit the `enum` keyword here.

Comment: Your function prototype must be declared outside main - before main. Move the declaration `void dіspl(int, int, enum data, ...);` before main begins and recompile. should work

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
void dіspl(int, int, enum data, ...);
```

above

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 0):

My compiler successfully compiled it. Looks like compiler problem. May be this will be work better:

```
void displ(int k, int i, int Type, ...){   
va_list arg;
va_start(arg, Type);

while(k--) {
    switch(Type)
    {
        case Char: while(i--)
            cout << va_arg(arg, char) << "     ";  break;
        case Іnt: while (i--)
            cout << va_arg(arg, int) << "     ";  break;    
        case Float: while(i--)       
            cout << va_arg(arg, double) << "    "; break; 
        default:
            cout << "Type=ERROR";
            return;         
    }
    cout << endl;  i =  va_arg(arg, int);
    Type = va_arg(arg, enum data); 

}

va_end(arg);
}
```

Comment: А який в тебе компілятор? Скажи будь ласка. В мене Visual Studio 2012 Express. Чесно, не знаю що з нею не так. Ще пробував через Sublime Text 3 запустити але не виходить

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2